# Glowing Eyes On Model Texture for export into ohter Programms

Tags: rendering, game-engine, effects

i find some cool Tutorial to how i can make cool glowing eyes on my little Model but they all for Rendering. Is is possible to have Glowing eyes on my Model Texture standalone ? So that i can import it into unity or unreal ? Or is it needed to make the glowing eyes in the engine itself ?

Hopefully i dont miss any other Post about this :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make my models in blender then and I color my objects at UV editing. After that I export my blender stuff to Unity as fbx files. I simply just export them to Unity and I create a new material. After creating my material I place my pallets to Albedo slot (Which you can see in the first image). Now you can drag and drop your materials to your objects material slot (which you can see in the second image).

[image]
[image]